# Framework7 same style for all platforms

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I'm developing an mobile app with Framework7(latest version) and PhoneGap. I want the UI of the app to be same on all devices(android and iOS). It uses the .md and .iOS classes according to the user OS. Is there any way to disable this and have the same styling for all platforms same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to explicitly declare which theme you want to use in the app.js initializing code segment below:

```
var app = new Framework7({
root: '#app',
id: 'com.yourbundle',
name: 'AppName', //
theme: 'auto', // Specifiy here: 'auto' or 'md' or 'ios'
```

**auto** is default and allows the system to select which theme to show depending on the platform. **md** will show material theme regardless of the platform, as will **ios**